# sscanf not working properly in mips platform

Tags: mips, scanf

The following code works correctly for x86 but not in mips platform.

---

```
  char *str = "11111111-22222222 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 1843624    /lib/libdl.so.0";
  unsigned long long start_addr, stop_addr, offset;
  char* access = NULL;
  char* filename = NULL;
  sscanf(str, "%llx-%llx %m[-rwxp] %llx %*[:0-9a-f] %*d %ms",
           &start_addr, &stop_addr, &access, &offset, &filename);

  printf("\n start : %x, stop : %x, offset : %x\n",start_addr,stop_addr,offset);
  printf("\n Permission : %s\n",access);
  printf("\n Filename : %s\n",filename);
```

---

### In x86 it outputs :

```
 start : 11111111, stop : 22222222, offset : 0
 Permission : r-xp
 Filename : /lib/libdl.so.0
```

### But in mips it is showing :

```
 start : 7ff20f5b, stop : 11111111, offset : 0
 Permission : (null)
 Filename : (null)
```

I used mipsel-linux-uclibc toolchain to compile. Can somebody help.

Comment: What if you don't use the dynamic allocation specifier (`%m`) and allocate space for the strings yourself?

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same result. I am very confused on how it is getting junk on 'start' value and actual 'start' value on 'stop'.

Comment: I was using %x instead of %llx. That solved the issue. But still filename is having problem. In x86 it correctly displays using %s, whereas in mips it is shown as null.

Answer (score 0):

The C code generates a segmentation fault on SunOS. So it works on Linux but not with RISC architectures lijke MIPS(?). You should investigate why using the `gdb`debugger, so use the command `man gdb` or run gdb and insert your breakpoints or I will do it as an exercise.